# IMAP -- what are the most popular versions used these days?

Tags: email, imap

I can't find any information about the status of IMAP version 4 and how widely it's used nowadays and how widely other versions, 1, 2 and 3 are used.

So is IMAP version 4 common these days? What about other the versions 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting this to the commonly used Linux servers:

- [Courier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_Mail_Server)
- [Cyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_IMAP_server)
- [Dovecot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovecot_(software))

They all support IMAP4, since the IMAP4rev1 RFC was defined more than 10 years ago, I don't think you'll find the older version still being used.

Comment: IMAP4 hasn't been released yet?

Comment: Depends on how you define released. These things are done as RFC once they are published, I would consider them released.

Comment: There are also mail clients that support it client side. E.g. Alpine. But I don't know if they have versioned support.

Comment: doesn't "ver1" imply that it's a draft version? or am I confusing it with "rev"?

Comment: @OskarK. revision 1 is, I would assume the first revised version after the IMAP4 base version. RFC 1730 from 1994 is IMAP4 without revision. A revision 1 is not the same as beta 1 as used in software releases.